# MVC4 LoginPartial (additional information)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, login-page

I am using MVC4 and SimpleMembership. Everything works ok, but I have a question about the _LoginPartial view.

This is the code of the partial view:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>
        Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
    </text>
} else {
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

How can I display a profile picture next to "Hello, user"? I have a User model which contains the filepath of the picture. This is also saved in the database.

Problem is I do not how to display it in a correct way.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RenderAction` that returns a `PartialView` that contains the image tag

```
    Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })! 
@{ Html.RenderAction("DisplayPhoto", "Account"); }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult DisplayPhoto()
{
   // query the user photo then return the view 
   ViewBag.FilePath = GetUserPhoto(username);
   return PartialView("_DisplayPhoto");
}
```

**PartialView**

```
<img src="@ViewBag.FilePath" alt="photo" />
```

Comment: So I can add Html.RenderAction to the _LoginPartial.cshtml file, add DisplayPhoto to the AccountController. For the PartialView: Do I need to create a new one or can I add that line (<img src..../>) to the _LoginPartial.cshtml view?

Comment: You need to create a new `PartialView` for the `DisplayPhoto` method. Also, the `AccountController` was just an example, you can change it if you want.

Comment: If I create a new PartialView it is blank, so I added <img src="@ViewBag.FilePath" alt="photo" /> to it, but it only displays the word "photo"...?

Comment: What did you save in the FilePath? You have to give it the absolute url of the image, exmple: `"~/Images/@ViewBag.FilePath"`

Comment: I implemented this: Server.MapPath(filepath); and filepath = ~Uploads\ProfilePic.jpg

Comment: Hm. Can you view the page source then visit the url that the image tag generated?

Comment: I checked the path with the DOM Explorer (of Google Chrome) and the filepath is correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40322/discussion-between-wannacsharp-and-odrai)